# Removes white spaces while reading in a file

Tags: python, removing-whitespace

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = (' '.join(line.strip().split())).split()
```

Can anyone break down the line where whitespaces get removed? 
I understand **line.strip().split()** first removes leading and trailing spaces from `line` then the resulting string gets split on whitespaces and stores all words in a list.

But what does the remaining code do?

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output you want to have? Are you trying to remove ALL whitespace from the line, or just at the beginning/end?

Comment: I'm reading the code written by someone else and trying to understand what this line of code does. The input is a .dat file that contains several rows of integers.

Answer (score 0):

The line `' '.join(line.strip().split())` creates a `string` consisting of all the list elements separated by exactly one whitespace character. Applying `split()` method on this string again returns a list containing all the words in the string which were separated by a whitespace character.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can it just be line.strip().split()? join and split() again doesn't seem to change the end result.

Comment: Yeah, the code is mostly redundant. @LearningToCode

Answer (score 0):

Here's a breakdown:

```
# Opens the file
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    # Iterates through each line
    for line in f:
        # Rewriting this line, below:
        # line = (' '.join(line.strip().split())).split()

        # Assuming line was "  foo bar   quux  "
        stripped_line = line.strip()     # "foo bar   quux"
        parts = stripped_line.split()    # ["foo", "bar", "quux"]
        joined = ' '.join(parts)         # "foo bar quux"
        parts_again = joined.split()     # ["foo", "bar", "quux"]
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I was asking. It seems to me the last two steps are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

That code is pointlessly complicated is what it is.

There is no need to `strip` if you're no-arg `split`ing next (no-arg `split` drops leading and trailing whitespace by side-effect), so `line.strip().split()` can simplify to `line.split()`.

The `join` and re-`split` doesn't change a thing, `join` sticks the first `split` back together with spaces, then `split` resplits on those very same spaces. So you could save the time spent `join`ing only to `split` and just keep the original results from the first `split`, changing it to:

```
line = line.split()
```

and it would be functionally identical to the original:

```
line = (' '.join(line.strip().split())).split()
```

and faster to boot. I'm guessing the code you were handed was written by someone who didn't understand `split`ing and `join`ing either, and [just threw stuff at their problem without understanding what it did](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: Thank you for the explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is explanation to code:-

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = (' '.join(line.strip().split())).split()
```

First `line.strip()` removes leading and trailing white spaces from line and `.split()` break to list on basis of white spaces.

Again `.join` convert previous list to a line of white space separated. Finally `.split`  again convert it to list.

This code is superfluous `line = (' '.join(line.strip().split())).split()`. And it should be:-

```
line = line.split()
```

If you again want to `strip`  use:-

```
line = map(str.strip, line.split())
```

Comment: No-arg `split` implicitly `strip`s, there is no reason to run it through `map(str.strip`, because every result from the `split` will have no leading or trailing whitespace. Similarly, `strip`ing before a no-arg `split` is superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

I think they are doing this to maintain a constant amount of whitespace. The strip is removing all whitespace (could be 5 spaces and a tab), and then they are adding back in the single space in its place.

Comment: Well, for one, the whitespace they added back is removed in the second `split`, so no whitespace is "maintained", let alone a "constant" amount (whatever that means; the stripped leading and trailing whitespace means even the number of runs of whitespace isn't preserved after all).